# SCCM 2007 Mandatory Assignment for a future date installs program now?

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

So I created an advertisment in SCCM and set a Mandatory Assignment to run in two more days, but the program started running on the clients already. I dont understand why it does this. Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check the radio button on the assignment tab. Even though you set a time in the scheduled section, if the selected radio button is `as soon as possible`, then it will install right away, which sounds like your issue.

[image]

Comment: As Soon As Possible was not selected, it was a scheduled date two days later.

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory just means that if it hasn't ran already on the machine since it's been advertised, it MUST run on (or after) that mandatory assignment.  It's kinda misleading as you'd think it would mean it would wait to start the install until that time, but that's not quite it.